# Operator and invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra

**Give an example of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb R$, an operator $T \in L(V)$, and numbers $\alpha $, and $\beta $ such that $\alpha^2 < 4 \beta $ and $ T^2 + \alpha T + \beta I $ is not invertible.**

I notice that I have to show $ T^2 + \alpha T + \beta I = 0 $ to show that it is not invertible. So I can just pick $\alpha = 0 $ and $\beta = 1$. Then I will have $$ T^2 + \alpha T + \beta I = T^2 + 0 + I. $$ 
I need to define an operator that would make $T^2 = -I $, then my above equation will be equal to zero and complete the proof.

Hence, please help me find an operator to complete my proof.

Thanks!

Comment: An operator doesn't need to be zero to not be invertible.

Comment: Would give me more hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an operator from your proof, but a different solution.

Let
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&-1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then 
$$
T^2=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&-1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Taking $\alpha=\beta=1$ we obtain
$$
T^2+T+I=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: That squared is $I$, not $-I$

Comment: @ZachEffman Corrected. However I am afraid not good enough for OP. I have checked: 21 questions, no one accepted. :-(

Comment: @KolaB. Your example would work for my question. Thanks!